# Lipschitz-continuity and measurability

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

> **Problem:** Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be Lipschitz-continuous with constant $L$. Let $\lambda_n$ be the $n$-dimensional Lebesgue-measure. Show that there exists a constant $C\ge 0$, s.t. $\lambda_n(f(A))\le C\cdot L\cdot \lambda_n(A)$ for every Lebesgue-measurable set $A$. Also show that it holds for $C=n^{n/2}$.

**Ideas:** I know that for every measurable set $A$ it is true that $A=B\cup N$ where $B\in F_\sigma$ and $N$ a null set. I also showed that $f$ maps a null set to a null set and a $F_\sigma$ to a $F_\sigma$ set. Thus we have $$\lambda_n(f(A))=\lambda_n(f(B\cup N))=\lambda_n(f(B))+\lambda_n(f(N))=\lambda_n(f(B)).$$ This is where I'm stuck, where do I get the constant from?

Comment: Are you sure that it is equality? I think that it is a inequality.

Comment: Oops, yes you are right, I didn't pay attention. Thanks!

Comment: Can you prove it for cubes?

Comment: I can prove it for cubes in a slightly weaker version where I get the constant C dependant on the cube. Can you give me a hint on how to prove it for an independant C?

Comment: I could prove it for cubes, but with a diferente constant. Assume that $A$ is a cube with side length equal to $a$. Let $d$ be the diameter of $f(A)$, hence we have that $$\lambda_n(f(A))\leq d^n$$ Note that (Lipschitz condition) for all $x,y\in A$ we have that $$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq L\sqrt{n} a$$ where $\sqrt{n} a$ is the diameter of the cube. We conclude from the last inequality that $$\lambda_n(f(A))\leq L^n\sqrt{n}^n a^n$$

Comment: That's what I had too. I'm thinking $n^{n/2}$ comes from the fact that the cube in the image can only be $n*L$ "longer" as the preimage for every dimension. Since there are n dimensions, the image can only be $n^n*L$ "longer" but since that includes "stretching in both directions" per dimension (since lipschitz continuity is defined in absolutes), but the lebesgue-measure is invariant under translation, we have $n^{n/2}*L$. I'm not sure on a formal proof tho.

Answer (score 0):

It is worthwhile to recall that for $n \in \mathbb{N},$ we have $\lambda_n(A) = \mathcal{H}^n(A),$ for all Lebesgue measurable $A.$ This is a standard consequence of Steiner Symmetrization, and $\mathcal{H}^n(A)$ is the $n-$ dimensional Hausdorff measure.

Now just use the definition of Hausdorff measure.

Comment: We did not define the Hausdorff measure yet, so I can't use that.